# Global State Mutex vs Lock

Tags: c++, mutex, raii

This question isn't specific to glfw, but it serves well to describe what I mean. In glfw, in order to start using any functions we need to call glfwInit() and when we no longer need to use them we call glfwTerminate(), I've been trying to come up with a way to wrap this around a RAII class, and I've found two useful ways to do it, but I'm not sure of the pros and cons of each one. In all of these I'm omitting the error-checking and the such, as they won't change the examples too much.

## 1: Using a Lock-like class

My first idea was to have a lock-like class that called glfwInit() at the beginning of it's lifetime and glfwTerminate() and the end, something like this:

```
struct GLFWLock
{
     GLFWLock() { glfwInit(); }
    ~GLFWLock() { glfwTerminate(); }
}
```

I realized that if two of these classes were created, then glfwInit and glfwTerminate would be called twice, so I added a ref counter and I felt like this was a fairly complete solution, aside from making it thread-safe  and possible others, but it would essentially be the same thing:

```
struct GLFWLock
{
    static size_t ref_count; /* = 0 in .cpp */

     GLFWLock() { if ( ref_count == 0 ) { glfwInit(); } ref_count++; }
    ~GLFWLock() { ref_count--; if ( ref_count == 0 ) { glfwTerminate(); } }
}
```

## 2: Using a Mutex-like class

After working with the previous model for a bit, I realized it is the same as a std::lock_guard with a mutex, in a way, so I thought I could make a mutex class and have the user do a lock_guard whenever they needed to use glfw, instead of offering just a lock.

I ended up coming up with this, which somewhat fits the concept of mutex according to the standard, ignoring a few of the formal requirements and focusing on what std::lock_guard will actually use:

```
struct GLFWMutex
{
    static size_t ref_count; /* = 0 in the .cpp */
    bool locked = false;

    ~GLFWMutex() { unlock(); }

    void lock() 
    {
        if ( !locked )
        {
            if ( ref_count == 0 ) { glfwInit(); }
            ref_count++;
            locked = true;
        }
    }

    void unlock()
    {
        if ( locked )
        {
            locked = false;
            ref_count--;
            if ( ref_count == 0 ) { glfwTerminate(); }
        }
    }
};
```

And then use it with std::lock_guard whenever it's needed, like a normal mutex.

I can see using the lock-like class is less that you have to type, since you don't have to declare a mutex and a guard, but would the mutex-like class be more useful? Possibly after adding more member functions like try_lock(), owns_lock() and others? Or is there a better solution to encapsulate this behavior?

#### Edit 1:

The usage syntax I'd like for this shared state would be something like:

```
struct glfw_shared_state
{
    static size_t ref_count; /* = 0 in .cpp */

     glfw_shared_state() { if ( ref_count == 0 ) { glfwInit(); } ref_count++; }
    ~glfw_shared_state() { ref_count--; if ( ref_count == 0 ) { glfwTerminate(); } }
};

struct Game
{
    /// While this Game object is alive, I want to share the state of glfw, so it isn't terminated
    glfw_shared_state state;

    (...)
};
```

Where every instance of game would up the ref_count by one, which would make glfw stay alive throughout game's whole lifetime, basically a shared_ptr, but for functions instead of an object

#### Edit 2:

As for the std::lock_guard, what I meant was something like the following:

```
/// This has an internal ref counter for how many threads are currently locking it
/// When it first starts with 0 threads and someone locks, it calls glfwInit()
/// Then everytime some other thread locks, it just ups the ref counter
/// After every thread using it has unlocked it and it's ref counter is 0, it calls glfwTerminate()
/// So this isn't locking anyway, it's just sharing a state
glfw_mutex global_glfw_mutex;

void draw()
{
    /// Make sure glfw is alive during this draw function
    std::lock_guard lock(global_glfw_mutex);
}
```

It's a bit convoluted, but it's essentially what I meant with the second example in the original post, I think that mutex and lock aren't appropriate words for this, but I think the comment convey the meaning I want the code to have, the 'lock' is just a shared_ptr essentially

Comment: @eukaryota The point of the `locked` variable is that lock and unlock can be called multiple times with the same object, so if it's a member variable, when the object is 'unlocked', it doesn't count towards the reference count, that means when calling unlock() it won't decrease the reference count, but if you do call lock(), then it will increase the reference count by one, if you then call lock() again, it won't do anything more, since it's already locked, and at the object's destructor, I call unlock() in case the object was locked, if it wasn't, then it's just ignored.

Comment: @eukaryota It's true a shared state fits this more, but I wanted to use this with std::lock_guard, so I modeled it after a mutex, but possibly if I called the first example, the lock, shared_GLFW it would fit it better? The first example, the lock, is pretty much a shared state, even though it's called a lock, so it might be possible I'm just mistaking the names of things here.

Comment: Your `GLFWMutex` is not actually similar to a mutex object then, but rather similar to a lock object. Multiple lock object refer to one mutex object, but multiple mutex objects are unrelated. I don't see how your class satisfies any concept of a mutex. For example going by the mutex idea, you would have one global `GLFWMutex m;` and then multiple `std::lock_guard<GLFWMutex> l(m);` where GLFW is used, but this will not work with your definition.

Comment: @eukaryota I think I'm confusing the terms here, and that's leading to me being confused about what do use. A mutex is similar to a unique_ptr, in the sense that only one user has access to it at a time, so what would be the word for something like shared_ptr while talking about threading? Because I feel like this shared state paradigm is what I need for here.

Comment: Maybe you can add an example of the usage you expect to the question, so we can figure out the correct terminology for it. I don't see how you can use your `GLFWMutex` correctly with a `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: @eukaryota I've explained both of the cases I'd possibly like to use this in, I'm not sure they have a terminology, but at the very least what I mean with it is a shared state that, if no one is using it, isn't initiated, and the moment at least one user uses it, it initiates and only destroys itself when there are no more users.

Comment: "A mutex is similar to a unique_ptr" **No**. They have completely different uses and meanings. Mixing them in your mind only creates confusion. "in the sense that only one user has access to it at a time" wrong `std::unique_ptr` says absolutely nothing about access. The only thing it says is that it is the only owner of a resource. It is true that a `unique_ptr` is not copyable and it is move only, but that doesn't mean only one user has access to it. And even if you look from this side, `std::mutex` is neither copyable, nor movable. So stop mixing apples and oranges.

Comment: Your example usage does not work (even thread-safety of the mutex aside). For example when two threads enter `draw`, both will call `global_glfw_mutex.lock()` but only the first one will increase the reference count. Then after leaving the first thread, GLFW will be cleaned up.

Comment: @eukaryota In the example both of them would increase the reference counter and in one of them glfwInit() would get called while in the other you'd wait for the other one to finish glfwInit(), then the one that finished last will call glfwTerminate().

Comment: @bolov I wanted to compare the owning mechanics of unique_ptr and share_ptr with the access mechanics of mutex, so for example shared_ptr has various owners, while unique_ptr only has 1, when you lock a mutex, there is only 1 accessor, which is the thread that locked the mutex, and I wanted to know the equivalent of shared_ptr, that is something that multiple threads can access, and when there are no more threads accessing it, it is terminated, of course this thing that's being accessed is atomic in some way, such as some functions.

Comment: No, there is only one global `global_glfw_mutex`. When the first thread enters `draw` and calls `lock`, its `locked` member is set to `true` and when the second thread enters `draw` and calls `lock` it does not increase the counter.

Comment: @eukaryota Oh, this glfw_mutex type wouldn't use a bool locked to determine if it's active it would use a reference counter, sorry, I thought I said it in the example, this 'mutex' is the equivalent of shared_ptr that I talked about a comment above, I'm just missing a name for it, and calling it a 'mutex' is just bound to bring more confusion

Comment: So `GLFWMutex` and `glfw_mutex_type` are not supposed to be the same thing then? If so, do you expect the usual behavior of `std::lock_guard` which waits until no other thread holds a lock (in this case "uses GLFW") or do you expect `std::lock_guard`'s constructor to always return immediately and simply increase the reference count?

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues you want a semaphore. Still the comparison with `unique_ptr` is very misleading.

Comment: @eukaryota I'm sorry, I seem to also have skipped over a few things in my head, I should maybe rewrite the whole question, but essentially yes they are the same, and it has both the ref counter and the valid bool, but I forgot that you had sugested the valid bool to be static, but it's actually just a non-static member in glfw_mutex. The valid bool is only there if you want to unlock and lock again midway through the function, else it would be possible to cheat the ref_count by calling lock() repeatedly

Comment: @bolov I've checked semaphore, it's close to what I want, just without a limit, and instead of carrying a bunch of data that is then split, it actually carries only a flag that enables all the functions inside glfw in this case for example.

Comment: I am still quite confused about your intentions second variant, but in any case the probable answer is that variant 1 with reference counter is the way to go (except that thread-safety needs to be assured by using an atomic reference counter), which is basically what a semaphore is.

Comment: Regarding GLFW specifically I also want to mention that the documentation states: `However, no GLFW function may be called from any thread but the main thread until GLFW has been successfully initialized, including functions that may called before initialization.`, in which case it is quite pointless to make this thread-safe, as it may never be used in a non-main thread.

Comment: @eukaryota Well for this particular case yes, it might be pointless, but it was the simplest example I could find that had a init() and a terminate() function that worked the way I wanted it to. Also I'll look into semaphore, now that I have the name, thank you. Also this question should probably be answered, so I'll do a bit more research, clean up the question and respond once I've learned of a good way of doing it.